# ExecuteReader requires an open connection

Tags: sqlconnection, executereader

I am getting the error: "ExecuteReader requires an open connection" and I know the fix is to add a connection.Open() / connection.Close(). My question pertaining to this error is more for me to understand exactly what happen under the hood.

I am currently using the "USING" statement which I expect it to open and close/dispose the connection for me. So I guess I don't understand why it didn't work as expected and I needed to explicitly code the connection.Open() / connection.Close() myself to fix the issue. I did some research and found people experienced similar issue because they were using static connection. In my case, I am creating a new instance of the connection... hence, it bothers me and hoping to get to the bottom of this instead of just fix it and move on. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnStr))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("mySPname", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //add some parameters

                SqlParameter retParam = command.Parameters.Add("@RetVal", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                retParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // fix - add this line of code: connection.Open();
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
                using(SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int success = (int)retParam.Value;
                    // manually close the connection here if manually open it. Code: connection.Close();
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(success);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;            
        }
```

Comment: `using` won't open the connection for you.  All that happens is that you've called `new SqlConnection(myConnStr)` with the guarantee that it will be disposed.  You still need to open it yourself once you know it's an appropriate time to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using does not open any connections, it only disposes of any allocated memory after calling End Using.

Comment: I was like.. how it did open it for me before and now I realized I had it open somewhere else. It makes sense now. Thank you. I knew it was something simple.

Comment: didn't know SO now actually delay accepted answer. I have to wait for over 5 minutes to accept your answer :(

Comment: better letter then never :)

Answer (score 0):

For the SqlConnection, you have to explicitly open it inside the using block, you just don't need to close it though.

I also notice that you are missing a set of brackets {} around the using SqlConnection. Maybe that's the issue? It should be like this:

```
 try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnStr))
        {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertProcessedPnLFile", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //add some parameters

            SqlParameter retParam = command.Parameters.Add("@RetVal", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            retParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // fix - add this line of code: connection.Open();
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            using(SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int success = (int)retParam.Value;
                // manually close the connection here if manually open it. Code: connection.Close();
                return Convert.ToBoolean(success);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's perfectly valid to chain multiple `using`s together as per the OP.

Comment: you can stack the using with no {  } to compact the code but not necessary a good practice. I just have a bad habit.